# How can I replace a 0.00 values to ' -' character in sql server requery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view below

```
Name    Ammount

Ivan     200.91
Ronnie     0.00
Ian       219.76
Kent       90.00
kelty       0.00
```

I want to replace 0.00 ONLY with character '_' but remember there is 90.00 which should NOT be replaced

what is the select SQL server  query I can use?

Comment: replace ` 0.00` with ` _`

Comment: It would probably be far saner to do this in whatever code/language is consuming your result set.

Comment: it is -   hyphen that needs to be inserted

Comment: Could you post the data type of Ammount column please?

Comment: The data is from a View

Comment: It still has a datatype.  You can use something like: `SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME'` to get hold of it.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT  Name,
        CASE CAST(Amount AS VARCHAR(10))
            WHEN '0.00' THEN '_'
            ELSE CAST(Amount AS VARCHAR(10))
        END AS Amount 
FROM Table
```

fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88abc/1

Comment: He need only values ` = 0.00` replace with `_`

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I foresee problems if `Amount` is, for instance, `230.00`.

Comment: Question was : `but remember there is 90.00 which should NOT be replaced`

Comment: This did not work, work, The result remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table
Set Amount = '_'
where amount = '0.00'
```

or

```
Select case when amount not like '%0.00%' then replace(Amount,'0.00','_') else amount end
from table
```

Comment: The result remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

After reading many other comments by the OP, I'm assuming that the datatype of Amount is varchar or similar.

If that is the case, then something like this would do the job:

```
declare @table table(Name varchar(20), Amount varchar(10))
insert into @table values ('Ivan', '200.91'),('Ronnie', '0.00'),('Ian', '219.76'),('Kent', '90.00'),('kelty', '0.00')

select Name, CASE WHEN Amount = '0.00' THEN '_' ELSE Amount END as Amount from @table
```

This returns:

```
Name                 Amount
-------------------- ----------
Ivan                 200.91
Ronnie               _
Ian                  219.76
Kent                 90.00
kelty                _
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: You need to provide the datatype for the Ammount column.  That error looks like my original answer, with assumption of decimal storage, was closer to the mark than your subsequent comments.